# How can i stop an event from the body, when clicking a button inside the body?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

So i want to create buttons when i click in the body, but when i click a button inside that body, i dont want to create another button. So how should i handle this? I tried with stoppropagation but is not working

```
           /*  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];*/

           document.body.onclick = function(event) {
                   var x = event.clientX;
                   var y = event.clientY;
                   var btn = document.createElement("button");
                   btn.style.position = "absolute";
                   btn.style.left = x + "px";
                   btn.style.top = y + "px";
                   btn.innerHTML = "click me";
                   document.body.appendChild(btn);
                   btn.className = "buton";
                   event.stopPropagation;
                   var butoane = document.getElementsByClassName("buton");
                   for (let i = 0; i < butoane.length; i++) {
                       butoane[i].onclick = function() {
                           alert("ai apasat butonul" + (i + 1));

                       }

                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try don't use `.onclick` better use [`.addEventListener(event, handle)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) then if you need you can remove event listener

You wrong write [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
let ev = document.body.addEventListener("click", bodyclick)
let butoane = ""

function bodyclick(event){
   let x = event.clientX;
   let y = event.clientY;
   let btn = document.createElement("button");
   btn.style.position = "absolute";
   btn.style.left = x + "px";
   btn.style.top = y + "px";
   btn.innerHTML = "click me";
   document.body.appendChild(btn);
   btn.className = "button";
   event.stopPropagation();
   butoane = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  butoane[butoane.length - 1].addEventListener("click", buttonclick) // add event only for just added button, not for all buttons again
}

function buttonclick(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation()
  alert("press button ", ev.currentTarget)
}
```

```css
body{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.stopPropagation` is a function, you need to call it, something like `event.stopPropagation()` but, in any case, that won't do what you are looking for.
You could ignore clicks to the buttons that you've created, something like this:

```js
document.body.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('buton')) {
    return;
  }
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.style.position = "absolute";
  btn.style.left = x + "px";
  btn.style.top = y + "px";
  btn.innerHTML = "click me";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.className = "buton";
  event.stopPropagation;
  var butoane = document.getElementsByClassName("buton");
  for (let i = 0; i < butoane.length; i++) {
    butoane[i].onclick = function() {
      alert("ai apasat butonul" + (i + 1));

    }

  }
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

What this does is to check if the clicked element has the `buton` class and if it does, return (don't run the code that generates a button).

Also, you could improve this, instead of going to every button you've created to reset it's `onclick` listener, you could do something like this:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  alert("ai apasat butonul" + butoane.length);
}
```